# how to parse json key thats starts with a number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get JSON data from sparkfun using ajax:

```
var public_key = "someKey";
var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "https://data.sparkfun.com/output/" + public_key + ".json",
    data: { page: 1 },
    dataType: "jsonp",
}).done(function (results) {
    // loop through results and log temperature to the console
    $.each(results, function (index, row) {
        console.log(row.1um_data);
    })
})
```

but it's giving me the error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

If I get rid of the number that the key starts with, or put a number elsewhere in the key, it doesn't give an error, so I'm fairly certain it's the number that it's starting with that's throwing it off.

I've tried row[1um_data], but it throws the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

If I just do `console.log(row);`, it shows that there indeed is a field in the JSON labeled '1um_data'.

How do I access JSON data with a key that starts with a number?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You have to do it like this:

```
row['1um_data']
```

Duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949523/json-keys-as-numbers).